# Controlling Voltage or Current with a PIC

Tags: pic, voltage, inverter

Although I have a fundamental understanding of electronics, I still have much to learn and this one has me stumped.

I am trying to control the speed of a TB Woods SM1 AC Inverter drive that in turn controls an AC motor. My options for speed control are a 0-+10v analog signal, a 4-20mA analog signal, or RS485 via a port by the same name on the drive to set the frequency (0-60Hz). I am unfamiliar with RS485.

Does anyone know how to control this with a PIC? I am planning on using the PIC18F4520. I can spare 8 bits of binary output pins, if I have to.

Comment: Can't get a datasheet from TB Woods without a login, apparently.

Comment: 'Amperage'? Do you mean 'current'?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way would be to use PWM and a low pass filter (with cutoff frequency well below the PWM frequency). The output of the filter will assume a DC level proportional to the duty cycle. For example if your Vdd is 5V, the a 50% duty cycle will give you 2.5V, 10% will give you 0.5V etc.
You would have to use e.g. an opamp with a gain of 2 to convert the 0-5V to 0-10V.

Comment: The OP says he needs +-10 volts analog, so the PWM output of the PIC can not directly generate this.

Comment: Add an op-amp to give a 2x gain?

Comment: and it's not +-10V but 0-+10V - I read that as 0 to +10V

Comment: @Majenko - I read it as 0 to +10V also (maybe the OP can confirm this)

Comment: @Majenko, I found a manual for another TB Woods inverter that specifies 0 to 10VDC, 4-20 ma, and RS-485 as interfaces to set the frequency, so you are correct.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the solutions...@Oli Glaser: It is 0 to +10V. @tcrosley: Thank you as well for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

RS485 uses a differential transmission pair (like the one used in USB) to achieve better noise immunity and thus longer cable lengths than RS232.  Otherwise it is very much the same -- you will no doubt be sending ASCII characters to control the frequency.

Since the PIC18F4520 has a UART, you can interface to RS485 using a TTL to RS485 converter.  Do a Google search for "ttl to rs485 converter".

[eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l2736&_nkw=TTL+RS485+-USB+-wireless) also currently has one listed for $11.

You can also build your own using the Maxim [MAX481](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/MAX481CPA+/MAX481CPA+-ND/1016414) if this is for a product.

Comment: Yes. More details listed at [Wikibooks: Common Protocols](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/Common_Protocols)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the noise in your environment. I say this because a motor is involved, and they typically can throw a lot of noise around, and the cables to them are usually long, which makes them look like antennas.

Some background on those options:

## 0-10 V Analog Voltage

This case is where you generate a voltage with a DAC or, as Oli pointed out, a filtered PWM channel. The key here is that any noise *voltage* picked up will create an error in the motor's speed. So you want to have two things that make sure that voltage is where you want it: a low output impedance (the op amp should be good for this) and high impedance at the input (probably the case, but check to be sure). The goal is for the driver (op-amp) to be stronger than any received interference.

## 4-20 mA Analog Current Loop

This is used in a lot of industrial systems. Usually, industrial controllers have 4-20 mA I/Os, but microcontrollers generally don't. The idea is that driving 4 mA onto the loop is one limit and 20 mA is the other limit; since there's always at least 4 mA, the device on the other end can use this as a power source, and since it's current and not voltage, the impedance of the line is less important than the loop area in determining interference sensitivity. Since the wires are usually in a twisted pair, the loop area is minimized.

Short version: This is probably too complex. Look at 4-20 mA loop driver chips to see what you'd need to do.

## 0-60 Hz RS-485

RS-485 is a multi-drop version of RS-422, which is a differential signaling protocol. There are two lines in a twisted pair, and the driver drives opposing voltages onto the wires. The receiver then just has to see which wire has the higher voltage to see if it is a logical 1 or 0.

In RS-422, there is one driver and one receiver, and a 100 ohm or so termination resistor across the two wires at the receiver end. In RS-485, there are multiple drivers and receivers spread around, the wire goes point-to-point between them (a daisy chain), and there are 120 ohm termination resistors at each end.

In your case, you just need to connect a timer pin to an RS-485 or RS-422 driver, and hook it up like the RS-422 case. Then program the timer to generate the needed square wave.

Comment: I couldn't find the manual for the specific TB Woods model specified by the OP, but I did find manuals for [other TB Woods models](http://www.geomartin.com/pdfs/commerical_components/Doc_000071_AC_Inverter.pdf) which indicate they are using ASCII commands over the RS-485 link, not a square wave.

Comment: Agree with tcrosley -- RS-485 generally uses ASCII commands; generally the software is exactly the same whether the UART is connected to a RS485 level converter chip or the UART is connected to a RS232 level converter chip.

Comment: Would love it if OP clarified, since he's the only one with the data on the device. And, yes, RS-485 is *usually* serial data; the exceptions are rare! One of those exceptions is the stuff I work on, where we use RS-422 to send timing information, and sometimes use PWM to send data along with the timing; it's not NRZ serial data in the slightest. So I'm waiting for clarification.

Comment: Thank you Mike for a VERY good answer. I mean't to ask Oli, but what does PWM stand for? I spoke with Vacon (TB Woods sold their inverter section out to them) and they said they don't know anything about the RS-485 to direct me further. Delta made these drives for them. I did get my hands on a manual. It is practically the same as what I have. Here is the link...http://www.icfilmmaker.com/supportdl/Form1283E-SM1.pdf ~Thank you!

Comment: PWM stands for "Pulse Width Modulation". It is a means of encoding information by changing the width of a pulse, as opposed to its position or frequency. In this context, the timers on the PIC probably have a PWM mode. You set (at least) two registers: one says how long the overall pulse is (rising edge to rising edge, usually), and the other sets the "high time" (rising edge to falling edge). If you low-pass filter it (Oli's context) then you get an output voltage scaled to the duty cycle (high time / pulse time).

Comment: In my RS-422 context, we use a 3X clock to generate a PWM output encoded with a clock, so a 1 in gives a 1 1 0 out, and a 0 in gives a 1 0 0 out. Note that the first bit is always 1, the last is 0, and the middle is the data. (It's not efficient with bandwidth, but it's easy to implement.) To recover the clock, pass the signal through a Toggle Flip Flop (TFF), which just inverts its output on every rising edge, cutting the frequency in half and restoring a 50% duty cycle, pass it through a 4X PLL to get a 2X frequency, and finally sample the middle of the cycle to get the data bit back.